# How to check search text contains in any field

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I Have a list data called `LogData`. Its code something like this.

```
var LogData = LogDataList.Select(data => new LogDataDto
{
    RowCount = RowCount,
    Location = data.LocationName,             
    Sender = data.FullName,
    AccountName = data.AccName,
    Messsage = data.Message
}).ToList();
```

Application gives me front-end value called `searchText`. I need to check that search text value is consists in any field in `LogData`

When `searchText = ""` I need to get all in the `LogData` and If `searchText` have some value, I need to check that value consist in any of this filels `Location,Sender,AccountName and Messsage` and nee to get those records.

So tried it as,

```
var result = LogData.Where(x => (searchText == "" || x.Location.Contains(searchText)) || x.Messsage.Contains(searchText));
```

Is that correct way to do this? How can I check search text value contains in other filed as well?

Comment: Yes this will work.  What is preventing you from expanding it to Sender and AccountName as well?

Comment: Probably slightly faster to do `searchText == "" ? LogData : LogData.Where(x => x.Location ...`

Comment: @DavidL Problem is I need good code practice to do it. Can u provide me code to do this for other fields as well sir

Comment: @Charlieface Can u provide me complete code to do this sir. is this correct `searchText == "" ? LogData : LogData.Where(x => x.Location.Contains(searchText) || x => x.AccountName.Contains(searchText)) `

Comment: here is an example doing what you want for jquery datatables in .net core   https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to search on four fields, you can continue to expand your OR conditions to include the additional fields.

```
var result = LogData.Where(x => (
    searchText == "" || 
    x.Location.Contains(searchText) || 
    x.Messsage.Contains(searchText) || 
    x.Sender.Contains(searchText) ||
    x.AccountName.Contains(searchText))
);
```

As Charlieface mentioned, you can potentially optimize this a bit by treating `searchText == ""` as an early exit condition and return your collection without a where clause.

```
var result = searchText == "" ? LogData : LogData.Where(x => (
    x.Location.Contains(searchText) || 
    x.Messsage.Contains(searchText) || 
    x.Sender.Contains(searchText) ||
    x.AccountName.Contains(searchText))
);
```